# Resize one subplot after removing another

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, resize, subplot

**Problem description:**
I'm building an interface for my lab, I intergrarted matplotlib with pyqt5 widget, there is a real time video display widget working on multi-thread and queue. I managed to show single shot with cross-section plot by adding divider. However, when I remove the cross-section plots, and redraw the figure_idle, the video frame can never moved back to its initial position with its initial size. I adjust the figure with navigator_tool_bar (top, bottom...), However it seems that there are blank areas left after removing the cross-section plots. Do you have any idea?

The initial figure:
[image: The initial figure]

Display cross-sections:
[image: Display cross-sections]

Clear cross-section and redraw:
[image: Clear cross-section and redraw]

**Video widget code:**

```
class VideoViewer(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=4, height=4, dpi=70):
        self.figwidth = width
        self.figheight = height
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(self.figwidth, self.figheight), dpi=dpi)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot()
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.975,bottom=0.048,left=0.029,right=0.983,hspace=0.2,wspace=0.2)
```

**Cross section code:**

```
    #create cross-sections
    self.divider = make_axes_locatable(self.axes)
    self.top_ax = self.divider.append_axes("top", 1.05, pad=0.2,sharex=self.axes)
    self.right_ax = self.divider.append_axes("right", 1.05,pad=0.2,sharey=self.axes)
    
    #create lines
    self.v_line = self.axes.axvline(xvlinepos, color='r')
    self.h_line = self.axes.axhline(yhlinepos, color='g')

    self.v_cross, = self.right_ax.plot(Norm_xvlinedata,np.arange(self.ImageData.shape[0]), 'r-')
    self.h_cross, = self.top_ax.plot(np.arange(self.ImageData.shape[1]),Norm_yhlinedata, 'g-')
```

**Clear cross-section code:**

```
    def ClearCrossSection(self):
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.pick_event_v)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.pick_event_h)
        self.h_line.remove()
        self.v_line.remove()
        self.v_cross.remove()
        self.h_cross.remove()
        self.right_ax.remove()
        self.top_ax.remove()
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

**What I did:**

1. Light_layout + subplot_adjust -----> does not work.
2. Constrained_layout -----> does not work.
3. Constrained_layout + GridSpec by declaring at beginning self.axes takes all cols and rows.-----> Does not work.

**An exemple of the problem:**

```
import sys

# GUI
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

# Matplotlib
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.lines as lines

# Generate data
import numpy as np
'''
need to update video frame, I'm using blitting, so better not clear the whole figure.
the whole code could be too long to show here.
'''
class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setGeometry(350,250,950,600)

        # Creat MainWidget
        self.MainWidget = QWidget()
        self.LayoutMainWidget = QGridLayout()
        self.MainWidget.setLayout(self.LayoutMainWidget)

        # Matplotlib widget
        self.MatplotViewer = VideoViewer()
        self.FigureTool = NavigationToolbar(self.MatplotViewer, self)

        # Button plot image
        self.ButtPltImg = QPushButton("Plot Image")

        # BUtton plot cross
        self.ButtPltCross = QPushButton("Cross View")
        self.ButtPltCross.setCheckable(True)
        self.ButtPltCross.setStyleSheet("background-color: Green")

        # add widgets
        self.LayoutMainWidget.addWidget(self.MatplotViewer,0,0,7,7)
        self.LayoutMainWidget.addWidget(self.FigureTool, 7,0,1,7)
        self.LayoutMainWidget.addWidget(self.ButtPltImg, 2,7,1,1)
        self.LayoutMainWidget.addWidget(self.ButtPltCross, 3,7,1,1)

        # Set central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MainWidget)
        self.connection()

    def GenerateImage(self, state):
        if self.ButtPltCross.isChecked():
            self.ButtPltCross.setChecked(False)
            self.MatplotViewer.ClearCrossSection()
            self.MatplotViewer.UpdateFrame()
        else:
            self.MatplotViewer.UpdateFrame()

    def PlotCrossSection(self, state):
        if self.ButtPltCross.isChecked():
            self.MatplotViewer.PlotCrossSection()

    def ClearCrossSection(self, state):
        if not(self.ButtPltCross.isChecked()):
            self.MatplotViewer.ClearCrossSection()

    def connection(self):
        self.ButtPltImg.clicked.connect(lambda state=True: self.GenerateImage(state))
        self.ButtPltCross.clicked.connect(lambda state=True: self.PlotCrossSection(state))
        self.ButtPltCross.clicked.connect(lambda state=True: self.ClearCrossSection(state))

class VideoViewer(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=4, height=4, dpi=70):
        # Figure
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        # Init Parent
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        # Ax
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.975,bottom=0.048,left=0.029,right=0.983,hspace=0.2,wspace=0.2)
        # Plot init image
        self.PlotInitFrame()

    def PlotInitFrame(self):
        self.ImageData = self.ImageGenerate()
        self.image = self.axes.imshow(self.ImageData, cmap='Greys', interpolation='none')
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def UpdateFrame(self):
        self.ImageData = self.ImageGenerate()
        self.image.set_data(self.ImageData)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def PlotCrossSection(self):
        # create axes
        self.divider = make_axes_locatable(self.axes)
        self.top_ax = self.divider.append_axes("top", 1.05, pad=0.2,sharex=self.axes)
        self.right_ax = self.divider.append_axes("right", 1.05, pad=0.2,sharey=self.axes)
        self.top_ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)
        self.right_ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=False)

        # set cross section limit
        self.right_ax.set_xlim(right=1.05)
        self.top_ax.set_ylim(top=1.05)

        # some pars
        xmin, xmax = self.axes.get_xlim()
        ymin, ymax = self.axes.get_ylim()
        v_mid = int((xmin + xmax)/2)
        h_mid = int((ymin + ymax)/2)

        # set line
        self.v_line = lines.Line2D([v_mid, v_mid], [ymin, ymax], color='r', pickradius=5)
        self.axes.add_line(self.v_line)
        self.h_line = lines.Line2D([xmin, xmax], [h_mid, h_mid], color='g', pickradius=5)
        self.axes.add_line(self.h_line)

        # set cross section data
        Norm_xvlinedata =  self.NormalizeData(self.ImageData[:,v_mid])
        self.v_cross, = self.right_ax.plot(Norm_xvlinedata, np.arange(self.ImageData.shape[0]), 'r-')
        Norm_yhlinedata =  self.NormalizeData(self.ImageData[h_mid,:])
        self.h_cross, = self.top_ax.plot(np.arange(self.ImageData.shape[1]), Norm_yhlinedata, 'g-')

        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def NormalizeData(self, data_temp):
        min_temp = np.min(data_temp)
        max_temp = np.max(data_temp)
        if min_temp != max_temp:
            return (data_temp-min_temp)/(max_temp-min_temp)
        else:
            return data_temp/data_temp

    def ClearCrossSection(self):
        self.v_line.remove()
        self.h_line.remove()
        self.top_ax.remove()
        self.right_ax.remove()
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def ImageGenerate(self):
        xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-502,502,1024),np.linspace(-502,502,1024))
        r = np.sqrt(xx**2+yy**2)
        AMP = np.random.randint(150,250)
        SIG = np.random.randint(200,250)
        T = np.random.randint(115,135)
        return AMP*np.exp(-(r)**2/(2*SIG**2))*np.cos(2*np.pi/T*r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Window()

    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: sorry, it took a moment to separate the code. https://github.com/jasonnlemon/Temp/commit/4f308ad05e60c92bb03e72ad2dd3ff0100850cea

Comment: No, the mre must be in your post

Comment: thank, so there is the code :)